# Images not showing on the Admin (back-end) after 1.9.3.7 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, image-upload, magento-upgrade, magento1.9.3.7

I upgraded my Magento CE to 1.9.3.7
When I try to upload images to the product manager no image shows up.

On the front-end, all previously added products show but not in the admin when I go to previously added products.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Open File `lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php`

Find this code

```
chmod($destinationFile, 0666);
```

And Replace it with

```
chmod($destinationFile, 0777);
```

Clear cache and check.

Comment: thanks for your answer: But I had to ask a developer to look deeper into this issue and he found that there was an incompatibility issue with one of the extensions (VES vnecoms marketplace extension). he fixed it

Comment: I am facing the same issue in VES vnecoms marketplace extension can you tell me what kind of changes you are doing ?